# How to install spree_static_content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

How do I install spree_static_content? I get following error.

```
In Gemfile:
spree_core (~> 3.0.0) ruby

spree_core (~> 3.0.0) ruby

spree_core (~> 3.0) ruby

spree_static_content (>= 0) ruby depends on
  spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta) ruby

spree_core (= 3.0.1) ruby

spree_core (= 3.0.1) ruby

spree_core (= 3.0.1) ruby

spree_core (= 3.0.1) ruby
Could not find gem 'spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta) ruby in any of the sources
```

At last it said that I need to do

```
bundle update
```

I did that but again get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The `master` branch of `spree_static_content` is, as if this writing, referencing 3.1.0.beta of Spree.  Any project using an older version of Spree, like 3.0-stable, will not be compatible.

To use this gem for a 3.0-stable Spree project, you'll need to use the branch of `spree_static_content` that is built to run against that version of Spree.  You can view it here:
https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_static_content/tree/3-0-stable

Your Gemfile should use this line to include the gem:

```
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Note the `branch:` value.  For other versions of Spree, find the matching branch of `spree_static_content`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what to do.

The error is:

> spree_static_content (>= 0) ruby depends on   spree_core (~>
>   3.1.0.beta) ruby

That means you need spree_core 3.1.0.beta or higher.

Running `bundle update` will not update a gem beyond the version specified in the Gemfile.

It appears you may have the same gem listed multiple times in your Gemfile, as well.

Try adjusting your gemfile to have just one entry for spree, of the appropriate version. It will probably look like this:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree'
```

Note that the [spree documentation](https://github.com/spree/spree) instructs adding spree, not spree_core. The spree gem will include the appropriate spree components of the correct version.

Please also not that updating spree is usually a little more involved than simply updating the version number and running `bundle update`. You will likely need to make other adjustments to your application to accommodate the new version.

Comment: It doesn't look like they have published one yet, probably they will when 3.1 is officially released. You'll just have to play around with it for now.

Comment: Or you can use the 3-0-stable branches.

Comment: It would if he used 3-0-stable branch for both spree and spree_static_content which is the current stable branch.  To get working on master branch he should try `bundle update spree`